# SQL select query in Python code within specific date range

Tags: sql, python-3.x, datetime

When I run the below SQL query within Python code, it will display me the rows I wanted (hardcoded way).

```
sql = 'SELECT column1, column2 FROM xyz_table where <date_column> like "2019-12-%" ORDER BY <date_column> desc'
```

I just wanted some help to run the same query but make it reliable as the query is supposed to run every month.

```
sql= 'SELECT column1, column2 FROM xyz_table where <date_column> like (datetime.date.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%") ORDER BY <date_column> desc'
```

In the above command, datetime is not working within the SQL query and I have searched but didn't find any way to use datetime within SQL query.

Can someone help me in finding a way to select data from table within specific dates using the Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to embed it in query string, something like this:

```
sql= f'SELECT column1, column2 FROM xyz_table where <date_column> like {(datetime.date.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%")} ORDER BY <date_column> desc'
```

UPDATE: The previous line raises error, the following example should work:

```
import datetime
dt = (datetime.date.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-')
sql= f'SELECT column1, column2 FROM xyz_table where <date_column> like "{dt}%" ORDER BY <date_column> desc'
```